# Trying to deserialize a session but no signature validation key specified

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am facing the following issue:
`org.mule.session.SerializeAndEncodeSessionHandler - Trying to deserialize a session but no signature validation key specified`
what results in session variable not being deserialized, thus I can't access them

The issue exists when I run the project on mule kernel 3.9.0.
It works fine on 3.9.0 runtime in AnyPointStudio.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a secret key in Java property mule.session.sign.secretKey to sign the session variables that are created by the collection splitter. This is a consequence of security patch: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Runtime-Security-Patch-31-October-2019

For example:
`-Dmule.session.sign.secretKey=REPLACE_BY_SECRET_VALUE`

See section 'Patch Configuration' of above article for details.

Comment: I added the following line to my wrapper.conf, but am still getting the error,  any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong here, or if I am missing something?  
  
`wrapper.java.additional.16=-Dmule.session.sign.secretKey=<key>`  
  
I generated the key in terminal using the following, as recommended in the article you shared:  
  
`dd if=/dev/random bs=32 count=1 2> /dev/null| base64`  
  
I have tried the key with and without encapsulating double quotes.  Still have the error that the OP mentioned.  It seems to be near the point we use a JMS connector.

Comment: @GarethPN, Could you please let us know how did you resolve this issue as iam facing the similar issue evethough after adding the secretKey.

Comment: Did you enable the enable the same patch and key in the Mule runtime sending the messages?